# Проблема с потоками Handler; java

Tags: java, android, android-handler

Пишу змейку. Хочу чтобы яблоко генерировалось с условием, если за 5 секунд змейка его не успела съесть.

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable r ;

r=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            invalidate();
        }
    };
```

Вот часть кода с отрисовкой
Все должно было быть устроено таким способом, что при условии, что яблоко не было съедено, идет счетчик шагов handler и при прошествии 5 шагов должно спавнится яблоко (и так через каждые 5 шагов).

```
    @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(0xFF1B007C);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrGrass.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(arrGrass.get(i).getBm(), arrGrass.get(i).getX(), arrGrass.get(i).getY(), null);
    }

    snake.update();
    snake.draw(canvas);
    apple.draw(canvas);

    if (snake.getArrPartSnake().get(0).getrBody().intersect(apple.getR())) {
        randomApple();
        apple.reset(arrGrass.get(randomApple()[0]).getX(), arrGrass.get(randomApple()[1]).getY());
        snake.addPart();
        Log.d("start", "Яблоко скушано");//Проверка
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (handler.postDelayed(r, 100)) {
                i++;
                Log.d("start", "Счет передвижений змейки");//Проверка
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    apple.reset(arrGrass.get(randomApple()[0]).getX(), arrGrass.get(randomApple()[1]).getY());
                    Log.d("start", "Рандом яблока");//Проверка
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
}
```

В итоге программа заставляет змейку статично увеличивать свою скорость, а яблоко генерится со скоростью движения змейки.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено! благодаря  System.currentTimeMillis()

```
public long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

 @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    timer = new Timer();
    canvas.drawColor(0xFF1B007C);
    for (int i=0; i<arrGrass.size();i++){
        canvas.drawBitmap(arrGrass.get(i).getBm(),arrGrass.get(i).getX(),arrGrass.get(i).getY(), null);
    }

    snake.update();
    snake.draw(canvas);
    apple.draw(canvas);

    if(snake.getArrPartSnake().get(0).getrBody().intersect(apple.getR())){
        randomApple();
        this.valueApple++;
        apple.reset(arrGrass.get(randomApple()[0]).getX(),arrGrass.get(randomApple()[1]).getY());
        main.appleValue.setText(Integer.toString(this.valueApple));
        snake.addPart();
        Log.d("start", "Яблоко скушано");
        this.start= System.currentTimeMillis();//начало подсчета

    }else{
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();//конец подсчета
        if(finish-this.start>=5000){
            apple.reset(arrGrass.get(randomApple()[0]).getX(),arrGrass.get(randomApple()[1]).getY());
            Log.d("start", "Рандом яблока");
            this.start= System.currentTimeMillis();//возобновление подсчета
        }
    }

    handler.postDelayed(r,100);
```